# Add effects (chaging pitch, frequency) and save audio to sdcard

Tags: android, mediarecorder, soundpool, audiotrack

I am trying to add effect in audio, I have recorded audio using `MediaRecorder` and added effects using `SoundPool` class now I am trying to save the effected sound but I found that sound i can't store a sound using `SoundPool`. Can any one please give a way to move on I am posting my code that records the sound and play it ...
Thanks in advance

```
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(getFilePath() + getFilename());

    try {
        mediaRecorder.prepare();
        mediaRecorder.start();
        setFlagRecording(true);

    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and to play sound

```
soundPool.play(getStreamID(), 1, 1, 0, 0, getFrequency());
```

Comment: no my friend i have tried hard but its just change the pitch and let me play the sound but don't find a way to save it ...

Comment: I end up using this library check it out: [SoundTouch](https://github.com/svenoaks/SoundTouch-Android/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: Thanks @AhmadKayyali